# HTML Table with 4 columns, outer columns are wider?

Tags: html, css, lit

I have a html table with 4 columns, but for some reason the outer columns are wider than the inner ones. This causes the images in the header to be different sizes and it looks odd.

Is there any way to force all columns to be exactly the same width, no matter what? If not, just having all the images maintaining the exact same height/width, but also remaining responsive

The CSS for my table is:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: relative;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```
tbody td {
  padding: 8px 12px 8px 0;
  width: 1%;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```
image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}
```

html of the table:

```
 <table cellspacing="0">
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the css rule for `tbody td`, change `width: 1%;` to `width: 25%;`

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that the table is variable. It will have between 3-5 columns.